# " react-infinite-scroll-component " Stopped working after migrating to React Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

InfiniteScroll is not working after I migrated to React Routes, `next={this.fetchMoreData}` is not called.
It was working fine before.

Code reference:

```
<InfiniteScroll dataLength={searchResults.length} next={this.fetchMoreData}  
    hasMore={this.state.hasMore} height={searchResults.length !==0 ? 776 : 0} 
    loader={<h4 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{t('loading_msg')}</h4>}
    endMessage={
    <p>
        {t('no_more_results_found')}
    </p>
    }
    scrollableTarget={'infiniteScrollContainer'}
    >
    {searchResults.map((searchRecord, index) => (
    // Populating data)}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Comment: "react-infinite-scroll-component": "4.1.0", // This is the verson have used

Comment: Issue got resolved 
removed 'height' prop from InfiniteScroll, added height to div

<div id={'infiniteScrollContainer'}
              style={{ height: searchResults.length !== 0 ? 776 : 0, overflow: 'auto' }}>
              <InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={searchResults.length}
                next={this.fetchMoreData}
                hasMore={this.state.hasMore}
                loader={<h4 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{t('nsp-help-app.loading_msg')}</h4>}
                scrollableTarget={'infiniteScrollContainer'}
              
                }
              >

Comment: Then remove this question or answer your self for the people who could have the same problem. I'm glad you could find a solution